# Ошибка в верстке

Tags: html, css

Я вывожу на главной странице интернет магазина товары, используя такую PHP функцию:

```
function render_catalog(){
// Функция выводит миниатюры всех товаров в каталоге продукции
    require_once('mysql.inc.php');
    $query = "SELECT id, title, text, keywords, price, quantity, images, availability, category FROM products";

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo "<div id=\"data\" class=\"row-fluid\">";
      $id = intval($row['id']);
      $title = $row['title'];
      $text = $row['text'];
      $image = $row['images'];
      $price = $row['price'];
      $category = $row['category'];

      if ($row['availability'] == 1) {
        $availability = "<span class=\"yes\">ДА</span>";
      }
      else{
        $availability = "<span class=\"no\">НЕТ</span>";
      }

      $currency = (string)$_GET['currency'];

      if ($currency == "USD") {
        $query = "SELECT rate FROM currency WHERE title='$currency'";
        $res = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
        $r = mysql_fetch_array($res);
        $rate = (float)$r['rate'];
        $price = round((float)$price/$rate, 2);
        $price_string = "<p><b>Цена: <span class=\"price\">\$ $price</span></b></p>";
      }

      if ($currency == "UAH") {
        $price_string = "<p><b>Цена: <span class=\"price\">$price</span> грн.</b></p>";
      }

      if(empty($currency)){
        $price_string = "<p><b>Цена: <span class=\"price\">$price</span> грн.</b></p>";
      }
      echo "<div class=\"span4\"><a href=\"single.php?id=$id&catid=$category\" title=\"$title\"><img class=\"showcase\" src=\"../img/$image\" alt=\"$title\"></a>
  <p class=\"text\">Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. $text. </p>
  <p><b>Наличие на складе: $availability</b></p>
  $price_string
  <p><a class=\"btn\" href=\"single.php?id=$id\">Подробнее &raquo;</a><a class=\"btn btn-warning\" href=\"basket.php?id=$id\" id=\"basket-button\">В корзину &raquo;</a></p>
</div><!--/span-->";
  }
  echo "</div><!--/row-->";
    }
```

Вот что получается в результате работы этой функции:
[image: Вывод товаров]
Обратите внимание как съехал вправо второй блок из трех товаров.

Особенно хорошо видно на мальком разрешении:
[image: Товары]
[image: Товары 2]

Видно как товары уезжают вправо. Как это побороть? Где ошибка в верстке?

Выкладываю HTML код этой страницы:

**UPD**: Выложил пример на http://jsfiddle.net/LFuVb/3/

Всем заранее спасибо за ответы.

Comment: ты лучше бы эту верстку выложил где нибудь. а то не понятно ничего. нужно просмотреть через анализатор html кода

Comment: Выложил HTML код странице на которой наблюдается бок с версткой...

Comment: Вы реально думаете, что кто-то, чтобы помочь ВАМ же, полезет разбирать эту туеву хучу макаронов только потому, что ВАМ САМИМ влом подготовить нормальный вид и восприятие проблемы и выложить все например на http://jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Уже в процессе...

Comment: css то выложы!!!!!!

Comment: исправил))

Comment: это вообще нормально что у вас id="data" повторяется больше одного раза ? и какой тайный смысл в том, чтобы для псевдоэлементов :before и :after  делать `display: table;`

Comment: ОМГ)) Дайте лучше ссылку, где можна глянуть на верстку "вживую" :)

Если локально - дайте свой IP и имя локального домена (по IP "вычислять" вас не буду, обещаю :DDD)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

в блоке с id #data убери  padding-left: 6px; и все